# Why this is not giving correct context while using promise?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, promise

I need to use Promise to execute things order in the following code. My actual save is ajax POST and want to call execute only after that successful POST.
Everything is working fine, but the problem is that I can't access the actual *this* variable, inside *execute* function. *console.log(this.abc);* gives me undefined why?.

```
  function MyClass(context) {
      this.abc  = "xyz";
  };

  MyClass.prototype.save = function() {
    console.log(" saving");
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      resolve();
    });
  };

  MyClass.prototype.execute = function() {
    console.log(" executing");
    console.log(this.abc);
  };

  var myInstance = new MyClass();

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(event.ctrlKey & (event.which==83)) {
      myInstance.save();
    } else if (event.ctrlKey && (event.which==69)) {
      myInstance.save().then(myInstance.execute);
    }
  }, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing a reference to a function to be executed by some other code, without specifying what to use as `this`.

Instead of

```
myInstance.save().then(myInstance.execute);
```

You can do

```
myInstance.save().then(function() { myInstance.execute() });
```

Because in that case you are the one calling `execute` using dot notation, which means that the object to the left of the dot will be used as `this` (`myInstance`).

You can also use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
myInstance.save().then( myInstance.execute.bind(myInstance) });
```

The lesson is, what matters is how the function gets called, it could be:

```
var a = {
  prop: 1,
  b: function() {
      console.log(this.prop);
  }
};
```

## Dot notation

```
// `this` will be `a`, logs 1
a.b();
```

## Loose function call

```
// If in strict mode, `this` will be undefined, and it will throw an error
// otherwise `this` will be the global object and it will log undefined
var b = a.b;
b();
```

## Using [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
var b = a.b;
// Call b passing a as `this` and 2 as its argument which is ignored
// Logs 1
b.call(a, 2);
```

## Bind `this` yourself

```
var b = a.b.bind(a);
// b has been bound to a, it will correctly output 1
b();
// Even if you try to use another this
b.call({prop: 2}); // Still logs 1
```

Comment: Thanks @JuanMendes it worked, is there any technical term which can describe this difference?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it can be technically described as "call time binding of `this`"

Comment: I got the idea about which this, context will be passed but can't still understand the usage of apply and call. what will be fun and thisArg in our case?

Comment: I meant to say why `myInstance.save().then(myInstance.execute.call(myInstance));` is not working?

Comment: That is because you are calling it immediately instead of passing a reference to the function, just as if you were doing`.then( myInstance() )`

Comment: `function() { myInstance.execute() }` looks ugly any other way to do it?

Comment: Added it to answer `myInstance.execute.bind(myInstance)`

Comment: Why answer this instead of just closing as duplicate of our canonical question?

Comment: @Bergi Because I thought mine was more concise for this specific case, then the OP asked further questions and I added more info